# Mysql Python, filter row and delete previus row

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm stuck doing a script in Python.
I have a table in MySql like this:

[image]

I want to filter the type of category (B, for example) and delete the previous row from above. I'm using mysqldb in Python, and practicing with selects and other operators, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: In this case, this would delete George ? Also, what happens if there are multiple `B` ?

Comment: Yes, I would delete George, if there are more than one "B" does not matter.
Thanks!

Comment: you are deleting previous one only? not all right

Comment: Yes, only the previous one

Comment: You first need to define the ordering. By default, db rows are not ordered so you won't always get the rows in the above order.

Comment: Do you have  unique/foreign key to ID column ? it will make job easy to delete if you have specific ID.

Comment: I have unique/autoincremental ID, sorry but in the image does not appear

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from Table where id=  ( Select id from(select  id from Table where CATEGORY = 'B'  and SALARY < ( Select SALARY from Table where CATEGORY = 'B' order by SALARY desc LIMIT 1) LIMIT 1) as x );
```